# how to call another class's method from within a managed bean class

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to create an JSF application that sends an email to the user upon registration.

I have a java class(CustomerSimpleMap.java) which implements the interface (CustomerLookupService.java).

I have a managed bean (CustomerSimpleMap.java).

```
    /**************************CustomerSimpleMap.java***********************/

    import javax.faces.bean.*;
    @ManagedBean 
    public class SendEmailBean {
        private String emailId;

            private static CustomerLookupService lookupService =
                    new CustomerSimpleMap();

        public String getEmailId() {
            return emailId;
        }
        public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
            this.emailId = emailId;
        }
    }
    /**************************CustomerSimpleMap.java***********************/

    /**************************CustomerLookupService.java***********************/
package com.tutorial;

public interface CustomerLookupService {
    public void email(String id);
}
    /**************************CustomerLookupService.java***********************/

/**************************CustomerSimpleMap.java***********************/

package com.tutorial;

public class CustomerSimpleMap implements CustomerLookupService {

    @Override
    public void email(String id) {
//method impl
    }

}

/**************************CustomerSimpleMap.java***********************/
```

**Issue:**

I am not able to use the **lookupService** object reference and access the **email** method in CustomerSimpleMap.java.

Please advise as to how a method of another class be accessed from a managed bean.

Comment: You can use `lookupService.email("someStringId");` inside a method in your `SendEmailBean` class. Your current problem is related to plain Java more than JSF.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
lookupService.email("abc"); 
is showing errors mentioned below:

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
  construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token ""abc"", delete 
  this token

Please advise.